# Подключение внешнего javascript с параметрами

Tags: javascript, html

Поставлена задача - написать js генератор кода для нескольких html файлов. Проблема в том, что результат работы js должен зависеть от того, в каком именно html документе его вызывают. Есть ли способ как-то подключать внешний js файл, передавая ему определенные параметры (например, одну переменную)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сервак отправляем что-то типо

`http://example.com/js/main.js?page=main&callback=firstHandler`

---

#### Через сервак раздавать но уже не как статику.

На серваке парсим url и получаем параметры.
Далее рендерим наш, заранее заготовленный, шаблон с js и отправляем клиенту.

---

#### Заготовленную заранее статику.

Так же можно заготовить несколько js, проверять на сервере параметр `page`, к примеру, и перенаправлять запрос на нужный файл.

Comment: А можно об этом поподробнее?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Есть вариант описывания кода в качестве библиотеки, а уже на нужной странице вызывать с нужными параметрами конкретные функции.

Answer (score -2):

Можно решить эту задачу, просто сделав вот так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
num=5; //переменная, которую мы передаем из html в нужный нам скрипт
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="вашкод.js"></script> //вызов скрипта
```

Comment: это глупое решение) зачем вообще тогда выносить это за основной .js файл? Ему нужно было с сервера отдавать тот или иной кусок кода для разных страниц.

Comment: не было серверной части в этом проекте